# Pandas filtering by column list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a function that returns a data frame that is DataFrame 'data' filtered to include only the columns specified by my list good_columns.

```
def filter_by_columns(data,columns):
   data = data[[good_columns]] #this is running an error when calling for my next line for: 

filter_data = fileter_by_columns(data, good_columns)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a function, you can the following:

Assuming your main `dataframe` is called `df`, you can create a new one with only the columns you specify using the below code,

```
cols_to_keep = ['c1','c2','c3'] # just enter the column names you want to keep
data = df[[cols_to_keep]]
```

Or, equivalently, **change your function to this**:

I created a random `df`:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1     5     1     5    10
1     2     4     2     4    20
2     3     3     3     3    30
3     4     2     4     2    40
4     5     1     5     1    50
```

Altered your `function` to this:

```
def filter_by_columns(data,good_columns):
   data = df[good_columns]  # have only 1 set of brackets here
   return data

good_columns = ['col1','col2','col3'] # assign the columns you need
filter_data = filter_by_columns(df,good_columns)
```

and the new filter_data `prints`:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     5     1
1     2     4     2
2     3     3     3
3     4     2     4
4     5     1     5
```

Comment: That is what I was using but it gave me an error when I was running my next line of code calling filtered_data= filter_by_columns(data, good_columns)

Comment: try the edited answer now, your function a bit changed.

Comment: Since its an exercise I am not supposed to change the first line or the line where it calls for filter_data = fileter_by_columns(data, good_columns)

Comment: Okay I changed it again. Check it out now

Comment: I got it! I was putting 2 brackets I change it to one and it ran! - Thank you Sophods!

Comment: Exactly. Glad I could help